# Why is Galand's armor color different between the manga and anime version?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In "Nanatsu no Taizai" season 2, there is a character named Galand, one of ten people from a group called The Ten Commandments. In the manga, his armor is green.

[image: Manga: green armor]

But in the anime adaptation, it's changed to ruby red.

[image: Anime: pink armor]

Is there a reason why they changed the color of his armor in the anime?

Comment: That manga coloring could be a fan art? Usually the manga scans and translators include a fan art.